# java key-value pair with key lookup as "startswith"

Tags: java, algorithm, collections

I am looking for a collection to store key value pair, where value should be returned on the basis of key `startswith` condition.
for e.g. for the given collection:  `(a,123) (ab,234) (abcd,5434)`

If I do `map.get(a)` it should give me array of `{123,234,5434}`, similarly if I do `map.get(ab)` it should give me `{234,5434}` but not `{123}` in this case.

So, it looks for all the values those have key with exact match or starts with.
Any suggestions? if there is something already available or if I can write something up?
Thanks!

Comment: Sounds a bit like a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Comment: In particular, you can use the Apache Commons Collections [`Trie`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/Trie.html) which can do exactly what you want. They have a [`PatriciaTrie`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/trie/PatriciaTrie.html) implementation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with `TreeMap<String,Integer>` using the [`tailMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#tailMap(K)) method, and iterating the result while the key matches the input:

```
TreeMap<String,Integer> map = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();
map.put("a", 123);
map.put("ab", 234);
map.put("abcd", 5434);
String myKey = "ab";
for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> e : map.tailMap(myKey).entrySet()) {
    if (!e.getKey().startsWith(myKey)) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(e.getValue());
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/bim2L4)

Answer (score 1):

Use a TreeMap, and create a special iterator that maps over your TreeMap and searches for the string pattern you are looking for

Comment: But wouldn't this approach be a linear time search ... which kind of defeats the purpose of maintaining the key-value pairs in a map?

Comment: search time of course is going to depend on how many elements match your string. But using the TreeMap structure, you can quickly eliminate lots of elements. For instance, if you had a tree will 1 million elements (even first letter distribution) if your search string started with 'a' you'd be down to approx 31250 elements (out of a million) in just 5 branch moves.

Comment: +1 Agreed. It will be linear, but not necessarily O(keyset.size()). In most cases, it will linear in the size of a much smaller subset.

Answer (score 1):

just a small touch on dasblinkenlight's solution:
Java 8 stream API provides a nice touch on the loop:

```
    TreeMap<String,Integer> map = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();
    map.put("a", 123);
    map.put("ab", 234);
    map.put("abcd", 5434);
    String myKey = "ab";

    Collection<Integer> matchValues = map.tailMap(myKey).entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getKey().startsWith(myKey))
        .map(e -> e.getValue())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: it is 50. I was below that number at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Following slanec's comment, I looked at [PatriciaTrie](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/trie/PatriciaTrie.html) from Apache Commons Collections4 and it really does have one method that does exactly what OP was asking for:

```
import org.apache.commons.collections4.*;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.trie.*;

Trie<String,Integer> t = new PatriciaTrie<>();
t.put("a", 123);
t.put("ab", 234);
t.put("abcd", 5434);
System.out.println(t.prefixMap("ab").values());
```